# Set a 0 result for LEFT JOIN that is blank?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have two tables joined by the foregin key 'ID':

table A has ID,MONTH,VOTES as well as table B ID,MONTH,OTHER_VOTES.

table A and table B as expected collect votes. Not all the time are there votes of both kinds.

I want to `LEFT JOIN` B to A so that on months that OTHER_VOTES don't exist (none, empty)  I would get 0 instead of an empty cell.

Is that possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is indeed. Where you select the column, use `IFNULL(OTHER_VOTES, 0)`.

Comment: Out of my own curiosity, is this the same as `COALESCE(OTHER_VOTES, 0)` or does `IFNULL(OTHER_VOTES, 0)` work better in this scenario? Trying to figure out why the `IFNULL` function exists if `COALESCE` does almost the same thing (less overhead maybe?).

Comment: coalesce accepts any number of possibly-null values and simply picks out the first non-null value. If you're only ever checking a single field/value for nullness, then use IF().